# Adding an Additional Struct to hold data which then prints out in the console window

Tags: c#

I have been given this code to change, I have already added a struct with the initial student information in it and it runs fine the code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Program
{
class Student
{
    public struct student_data
    {
        public string forename;
        public string surname;
        public string prog_title;
        public string prog_code;
        public int id_number;
        public float averageGrade;

    }

    static void populateStruct(out student_data student, string fname, string surname,            string prog_title, string prog_code, int id_number)
    {
        student = new student_data();
        student.forename = fname;
        student.surname = surname;
        student.prog_title = prog_title;
        student.prog_code = prog_code;
        student.id_number = id_number;
        student.averageGrade = 0.0F;

    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        student_data[] students = new student_data[4];
        populateStruct(out students[0], "Mark", "Anders", "Comp", "CIS2117", 0);
        printStudent(students[0]);
        populateStruct(out students[1], "Tom", "Jones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 1);
        printStudent(students[1]);
        populateStruct(out students[2], "Tim", "Jones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 2);
        printStudent(students[2]);
        populateStruct(out students[3], "Tim", "Bones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 3);
        printStudent(students[3]);
    }
    void printAllStudent(student_data student)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
    }


    static void printStudent(student_data student)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + student.forename + " " + student.surname); 
        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + student.id_number);
        Console.WriteLine("AV grade: " + student.averageGrade);
        Console.WriteLine("Course Title: " + student.prog_title);
        Console.WriteLine("Course Code: " + student.prog_code);


    }
}
```

}

But I was tasked with adding another Struct to hold module_data which I've done, I've also created a new method to populate the module_data array. But when I run the program only one error shows up and nothing happens?

It is meant to WriteLine all the elemmnts in the arrays in the console screen but will not build and produces this error:

'Error  1   The type or namespace name 'module_data' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

The Code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;  
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Program
{
class Student
{
    public struct student_data
    {
        public string forename;
        public string surname;
        public string prog_title;
        public string prog_code;
        public int id_number;
        public float averageGrade;

    }

    public struct module_data
    {
        public string module_code;
        public string module_title;
        public int module_mark;
    }

    static void populateStruct(out student_data student, string fname, string surname,    string prog_title, string prog_code, int id_number)
    {
        student = new student_data();
        student.forename = fname;
        student.surname = surname;
        student.prog_title = prog_title;
        student.prog_code = prog_code;
        student.id_number = id_number;
        student.averageGrade = 0.0F;

    }

    static void populateModule(out module_data module, string mcode, string mname, int   (score)
    {
        module = new module_data();
        module.module_code = mcode;
        module.module_title = mname;
        module.module_mark = score;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        {
            student_data[] students = new student_data[5];
            populateStruct(out students[0], "Mark", "Anderson", "Comp", "CIS2117", 0);
            printStudent(students[0]);
            populateStruct(out students[1], "Tom", "Jones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 1);
            printStudent(students[1]);
            populateStruct(out students[2], "Tim", "Jones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 2);
            printStudent(students[2]);
            populateStruct(out students[3], "Tim", "Bones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 3);
            printStudent(students[3]);
        }
        {
            module_data[] modules = new module_data[4];
            populateStruct(out modules[0], "7", "App Dev", "56", 0);
            printStudent(modules[0]);
            populateStruct(out modules[1], "7", "App Dev", "56", 1);
            printStudent(module[1]);
            populateStruct(out modules[2], "7", "App Dev", "56", 2);
            printStudent(modules[2]);
            populateStruct(out modules[3], "7", "App Dev", "56", 3);
            printStudent(modules[3]);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    void printAllStudent(student_data student)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);

        }
    }


    static void printStudent(student_data student)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + student.forename + " " + student.surname);
        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + student.id_number);
        Console.WriteLine("AV grade: " + student.averageGrade);
        Console.WriteLine("Course Title: " + student.prog_title);
        Console.WriteLine("Course Code: " + student.prog_code);
        Console.WriteLine("Module Code: " + modules.mcode);
        Console.WriteLine("Module Name: " + modules.mname);
        Console.WriteLine("Score: " + modules.score);

    }
}
```

}

In all truth not sure where I've gone wrong, any help or advice would be appreciated.

Comment: On what line are you getting the error? Also, that is really really not what structs are for. You really should be using classes for that..!

Comment: Also - you should be getting other errors. You're calling `populateStruct` passing `module_data` when you should be calling `populateModule`. Edit: and `printStudent` on `module_data` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if a `module` is something a `student` has.  This answer has them independent.  Although the code needs additional work this will at least clean up your code and get you started.  There are naming conventions that aren't followed here and other standards.

I would suggest you write one small piece of functionality and get that to work before moving on to something else.  You had many errors in your code which wouldn't compile.  Fixing an error as it occurs and testing small pieces will help you figure out what the problem is.

**The links below are to explain comments in the code**

[Choosing Between Class and Struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017.aspx)

[Default constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645608%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

[How to: Initialize Objects by Using an Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397680.aspx)

[Array Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.aspx) showing it implements `IEnumerable`

```
class Program
{
    //Use a class instead of a struct to store your data in most cases... see link
    public class Student
    {
        public string forename { get; set; }
        public string surname { get; set; }
        public string prog_title { get; set; }
        public string prog_code { get; set; }
        public int id_number { get; set; }
        public float averageGrade { get; set; }

        //I ommited the defualt {} constructor so this is your only choice to create a new class
        //you may want to choose to put it back in for more flexibility...see link
        public Student(string fname, string surname, string prog_title, string prog_code, int id_number)
        {
            forename = fname;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.prog_title = prog_title;
            this.prog_code = prog_code;
            this.id_number = id_number;
            averageGrade = 0.0F;
        }
    }

    public class module_data
    {
        public string module_code { get; set; }
        public string module_title { get; set; }
        public int module_mark { get; set; }

        public module_data(string mcode, string mname, int score)
        {
            module_code = mcode;
            module_title = mname;
            module_mark = score;
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //I'm initializing the array using object initialization syntax ... see link
        Student[] students = new Student[4]
            {
                new Student( "Mark", "Anderson", "Comp", "CIS2117", 0),
                 new Student( "Tom", "Jones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 1),
                 new Student ("Tim", "Jones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 2),
                 new Student( "Tim", "Bones", "Comp", "CIS2117", 3)
            };

        module_data[] modules = new module_data[4]
        {
            new module_data( "7", "App Dev", 0),
            new module_data( "7", "App Dev", 1),
            new module_data("7", "App Dev", 2),
            new module_data("7", "App Dev", 3)
        };

        printAllStudent(students);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    //Because an array implements IEnumerable you should use a foreach loop instead of a for loop
    static void printAllStudent(Student[] students)
    {
        foreach (Student s in students)
        {
            printStudent(s);
        }
    }

    //You could pass a null in here and this would have a run-time error.
    //It would be safer to check if student!=null here first (but I left it for you)
    static void printStudent(Student student)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + student.forename + " " + student.surname);
        Console.WriteLine("Id: " + student.id_number);
        Console.WriteLine("AV grade: " + student.averageGrade);
        Console.WriteLine("Course Title: " + student.prog_title);
        Console.WriteLine("Course Code: " + student.prog_code);
    }

    static void printModule(module_data m)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Module Code: " + m.module_code);
        Console.WriteLine("Module Name: " + m.module_title);
        Console.WriteLine("Score: " + m.module_mark);

    }
}
```